# anyone give me a list of Healthy Foods to Crank Up my Sex Drive?

Tags: nutrition, health-education, libido, sexual-arousal

I find difficulties when I sleep with my wife to do the sex I heard that there are food to become good in sex please help me :(

Answer (score 2):

Maca <--- Really healthy in general also.

Horny Goat's Weed <--- Haven't tried it myself.

I think generally you're looking for herb-aphrodisiacs. Try a google search and I'm sure you'll find lots of resources.

That said, improving nutrition in general is key to most health-issues I believe. Avoid refined carbs (sugars), eat more fiber, if you live in Europe (like me) take a vitamin D supplement in the Winter, take a multisupp aswell, supp with magnesium and potassium also. Aim for correcting potential micronutrient deficiencies - you'll have to research a little to get a general understanding. A good one for overall health is fish-oil.
Also some regular exercise does wonder for your sexdrive, doesn't have to be fitness, running is a fantastic tool imo.